# use okhttp with junit4 cannot get response data

Tags: kotlin, okhttp, junit4

I found a confuse problem when I use okhttp with Junit in a kotlin project

by the way ,here is my environment:

- okhttp 4.9.0
- junit 4.12
- kotlin 1.4.20

here is my simple code:

```kotlin
class SingleFileDownloadTest {
    @org.junit.Test
    fun testDownloadSingleFile() {
        val client =  OkHttpClient()

        val request= Request.Builder().url("https://www.imooc.com/learn/1141").build()
        val call = client.newCall(request)

        //console outputs this log successfully
        
        // println(call.execute().body?.string())

        call.enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                //this is wrong,I don't see the log in the console
                println(response.body?.string())
                println("resp success")
            }
        })

    }
}
```

I think there is a wrong in the call.enqueue() or something other reason for this solution？

Thanks for help

I want to use okhttp with junit4 to get data of response successfully

Answer (score 0):

I get an answer that `JUnit` cannot support `multi-thread`.

Let the thread sleep can resolve this problem

```kotlin
class SingleFileDownloadTest {
    @org.junit.Test
    fun testDownloadSingleFile() {
        val client =  OkHttpClient()

        val request= Request.Builder().url("https://www.imooc.com/learn/1141").build()
        val call = client.newCall(request)

        //console outputs this log successfully
        
        // println(call.execute().body?.string())

        call.enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                //this is wrong,I don't see the log in the console
                println(response.body?.string())
                println("resp success")
            }
        })

     Thread.sleep(10*1000)
    }
}
```